# Erlang understand recursion

Tags: recursion, erlang

I have some problems understanding recursion and I was hoping for some help. I have 2 examples with answers but I can't understand how the outcomme was calculated.

```
f1(X, [X | Ys]) -> [X] ++ f1(X, Ys);
f1(X, [Y| Xs]) -> tl(f1(Y, Xs)) ++ [X];
f1(X, []) -> [X,X].
```

If I run that code with: f1(2, [1,1,1,6]). I will get -> [1,6,1,2]

another example: f1(c, [f,b,d,d,a]) -> [b,f,c]

Can somebody please explain to me how this function calculates? :)

Another recursion function that I can't grasp is this one:

```
f2([X|Xs]) when X > 2 ->
  [X|f2(XS)];
f2([X|Xs]) ->
  [Y|Ys] = f2(Xs),
  [Y,X+Y|Ys];
f2([]) -> [1].
```

Example: f2([3,1,2]). -> [3,1,2,3]. How is that?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These examples make use of Erlang's pattern matching.

The first clause of the first example will match if the first element of the list is exactly the same as first argument

```
f1(X, [X | Ys]) -> [X] ++ f1(X, Ys);
```

The second clause will match all other cases where the list is not empty

```
f1(X, [Y| Xs]) -> tl(f1(Y, Xs)) ++ [X];
```

And the last clause matches the empty list.

```
f1(X, []) -> [X,X].
```

When evaluating `f1(2, [1,1,1,6]).` the first iteration matches the second clause, setting `X=2`, `Y=1`, `Xs=[1,1,6]` then calling `f1(1,[1,1,6])` and returning the tail of that result with `2` appended

The second iteration `f1(1,[1,1,6])` then matches the first clause, setting `X=1`, `Ys=[1,6]`, then calling `f1(1,[1,6])` and returning that result with `1` prepended

The third iteration `f1(1,[1,6])` also matches the first clause, setting `X=1`, `Ys=[6]`, then calling f1(1,[6]), and returning that result with `1` prepended

The fourth iteration `f1(1,[6])` matches the second clause, setting `X=1`, `Y=6`, `Xs=[]` then calling `f1(6,[])`, dropping the first element, and appending `1` to the result

The final iteration matches the third clause, setting `X=6` and returning `[6,6]`

Unwinding up the stack then:

- drop the first element from [6,6] and append `1` -> returns [6,1] (fourth call)
- prepend `1` -> returns [1,6,1] (third call)
- prepend `1` -> returns [1,1,6,1] (second call)
- append `2` to the tail -> returns [1,6,1,2] (first call)

for a final value of [1,6,1,2]

In your second example, the first clause is only used for the first element.  Note that since a proper list ends with an empty list, the pattern match `[Y|Ys] = [1]` will set `Y=1` and `Ys=[]`

Edit: adding explanation of the second example

```
%% If the first item in the list is greater than 2, 
%% return a new list consisting of the first item prepended 
%% to the result of recursively processing the rest of the list
f2([X|Xs]) when X > 2 ->
  [X|f2(XS)];

%% In all other cases where the list is not empty, save off 
%% the first element, then create a new list whose first 
%% element is the first element returned by the recursive call, 
%% and whose second element is the sum of that element and the 
%% first element saved above, with the rest of the recursive 
%% result appended
f2([X|Xs]) ->
  [Y|Ys] = f2(Xs),
  [Y,X+Y|Ys];

%% return 1 if passed an empty list
f2([]) -> [1].
```

So then following the execution:

```
1a. `f2([3,1,2])` matches the first clause, setting `X=3`, `Xs=[1,2]`

     2a. `f2([1,2])` matches the second clause, setting `X=1`, `Xs=[2]`  

         3a. `f2([2])` matches the second clause, setting `X=2`, `Xs=[]`

             4. `f2([])` matches the second clause, returning [1]

         3b. `[Y|Ys] = [1]` sets `Y=1`, `Ys=[]`

         3c. returns `[1, 1 + 2 | []]` i.e. `[1,3]`

     2b. `[Y|Ys] = [1,3]` sets `Y=1`, `Ys=[3]`

     2c. returns `[1, 1 + 1 | [3]]` i.e. `[1,2,3]`

 1b.  returns `[3|[1,3,2]]` i.e. `[3,1,2,3]`
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast quick answer
"then calling f1(6,[]), dropping the first element, and appending 1 to the result

The final iteration matches the third clause, setting X=6 and returning [6,6]" I got lost here. What happends to the other 6 in [6,6]? and what do you mean with dropping the first element? :)

Comment: The function `tl` returns the tail of a list, i.e. the list with its first element removed, which is how the second clause mutates the result of the recursive call before returning.

Comment: Ahaaa! Yeah I got it!! :D Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to solve the second one but I get stuck. First call will match first clause making it [3 | f4([1,2])]. So f4(1,2) -> Second. Making Y = 2? and Ys= [] -> f4(2), [2,3 | []]?

Comment: In the seoncd clause, the `[Y|Ys]` pattern match is applied to the value returned by the recursive call, not the passed argument.  I've edited the answer to add an explanation of the second example

Comment: Thanks again @Joe, I will go trough it tomorrow with the help of your post :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joe answer, you can visualize the function execution thanks to the dbg module. I put the f1/2 function in a module named expl.erl and here is what you can get in a shell:

```
1> c(expl).  % compile the module                                            
{ok,expl}
2> dbg:tracer().  % start the dbg module                                     
{ok,<0.66.0>}
3> dbg:p(all, c).  % ask to trace every call                                    
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,26}]}
4> % show return value of calls to expl:f1/2
4> dbg:tpl(expl, f1, 2, [{'_', [], [{return_trace}]}]).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,1},{saved,1}]}
5> expl:f1(2, [1,1,1,6]).   % now call the function and see each call and the returned values                           
[1,6,1,2]
(<0.49.0>) call expl:f1(2,[1,1,1,6])
(<0.49.0>) call expl:f1(1,[1,1,6])
(<0.49.0>) call expl:f1(1,[1,6])
(<0.49.0>) call expl:f1(1,[6])
(<0.49.0>) call expl:f1(6,[])
(<0.49.0>) returned from expl:f1/2 -> [6,6]
(<0.49.0>) returned from expl:f1/2 -> [6,1]
(<0.49.0>) returned from expl:f1/2 -> [1,6,1]
(<0.49.0>) returned from expl:f1/2 -> [1,1,6,1]
(<0.49.0>) returned from expl:f1/2 -> [1,6,1,2]
6> dbg:stop_clear().  % stop dbg and clear trace                                  
ok
7>
```

Comment: thanks I did not know that :) I'm trying that code on the second part of my post but I still can't figure it out. Could you maybe post a step by step if you have the time?